# BindingImpl class for fragment not generated when using data binding onClick expression

Tags: android, gradle, data-binding

In my `Fragment`s layout I have a button which is using the XML `onClick` expression to call a method in the corresponding `ViewModel`.

The problem is that upon building the project, the compiler throws following error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
import com.aresid.myapp.databinding.FragmentLoginBindingImpl;
                                    ^
symbol:   class FragmentLoginBindingImpl
location: package com.aresid.myapp.databinding
```

The thing is that, when I remove the parameters from the functions signature and the functions call in the XML, the app builds without problems.

My expectation is that, when I click the login button, the method in the `ViewModel` would be called, logging the `emailField.text` and `passwordField.text`.

**The layout file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >

    <data>

        <variable
            name="loginViewModel"
            type="com.aresid.myapp.login.LoginViewModel"
            />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/fragmentPaddingMedium"
        tools:context=".login.LoginFragment"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/app_logo"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/imageViewAppLogoSize"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/imageViewAppLogoSize"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/my_app_logo"
            android:src="@drawable/my_app_logo_144"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/email_field_layout"
            style="@style/Widget.MyApp.TextInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/app_logo"
            >

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/email_field"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/password_field_layout"
            style="@style/Widget.MyApp.TextInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email_field_layout"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
            >

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/password_field"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:imeActionId="6"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/common_signin_button_text"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            style="@style/Widget.MyApp.ContainedButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/log_in"
            android:onClick="@{() -> loginViewModel.onLoginButtonClicked(emailField.text, passwordField.text)}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password_field_layout"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
            android:text="@string/sign_up_using_these_colon"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/signup_button_container"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/signup_button_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="13dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            >

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:id="@+id/email_signup_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="6.5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button_background"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_email_24dp"
                />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:id="@+id/google_signup_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="6.5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button_background"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_google_favicon_24dp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**The corresponding `ViewModel`:**

```
package com.aresid.myapp.login

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import timber.log.Timber

/**
 * Created on: 27/04/2020
 * For Project: MyApp
 * Author: René Spies
 * Copyright: © 2020 ARES ID
 */

class LoginViewModel: ViewModel() {

    // LiveData for the login email
    private val _email = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val email: LiveData<String>
        get() = _email

    // LiveData for the login password
    private val _password = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val password: LiveData<String>
        get() = _password

    // LiveData for the login button
    private val _wantLogin = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val wantLogin: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _wantLogin

    init {

        Timber.d("init: called")

        // TODO:  init: init objects here

        // Init email LiveData
        _email.value = ""

        // Init password LiveData
        _password.value = ""

        // Init wantLogin LiveData
        _wantLogin.value = false

    }

    fun onLoginButtonClicked(email: String, password: String) {

        Timber.d("onLoginButtonClicked: called")
        Timber.d("email = $email\npassword = $password")
        // TODO:  onLoginButtonClicked: log in user

    }

}
```

**And the `Fragment`s `onCreateView()`:**

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        Timber.d("onCreateView: called")

        // Define LoginViewModel
        loginViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(LoginViewModel::class.java)

        // Define FragmentLoginBinding and inflate the layout
        binding = FragmentLoginBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        // TODO:  onCreateView: code goes here

        // Let the data binder know about the LoginViewModel
        binding.loginViewModel = loginViewModel

        // Return the inflated layout
        return binding.root

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Use [Two-way Databinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way) for your e-mail and password. By this your ViewModel fields will change automatically after user changes them in UI:

   `android:text="@={viewmodel.password}"`
2. Your function "onLoginButtonClicked" can now be declared without parameters (these values are hold now as fields of ViewModel so you can get them freely inside function).
3. In your xml change the onClick as well:

   `android:onClick="@{() -> loginViewModel.onLoginButtonClicked()}"`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unluckily, it did not work for me. I did as you wrote above and used the Two-way Databinding. I also tried the BaseObservable thing from the your link.

Comment: Actually you can use your current LiveData instead of Observable (but maybe change private to public), DataBinding works well with it. So what do you mean by "it did not work"? You still have the same build error? [There](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/android-data-binding-library-from-observable-fields-to-livedata-in-two-steps-690a384218f2) you can read about LiveData (first article from official docs is little outdated).

Comment: Oh god. Changing the LiveData from private to public did solve the problem. Before that, yes I got the same build error. Anyhow, thank you so much for your help.